# Why i don't inject in ViewModel i use Hilt for kotlin

Tags: viewmodel, dagger-hilt

```
@HiltViewModel
class PrincipalViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: PrincipalRepository) :ViewModel()
```

there is my binds

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class ActivityModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindPrincipalRepoImpl(repoImpl : PrincipalRepositoryImpl) : PrincipalRepository
}
```

And the error is

/Users/X/AndroidStudioProjects/Corotuines/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/example/corotuines/application/ApplicationMain_HiltComponents.java:126: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.corotuines.repository.PrincipalRepositoryImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements ApplicationMain_GeneratedInjector,
^
com.example.corotuines.repository.PrincipalRepositoryImpl is injected at
com.example.corotuines.di.ActivityModule.bindPrincipalRepoImpl(repoImpl)
com.example.corotuines.repository.PrincipalRepository is injected at
com.example.corotuines.viewmodel.PrincipalViewModel(repository)
com.example.corotuines.viewmodel.PrincipalViewModel is injected at
com.example.corotuines.viewmodel.PrincipalViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.corotuines.application.ApplicationMain_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.example.corotuines.application.ApplicationMain_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.example.corotuines.application.ApplicationMain_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]

Answer (score 0):

If PrincipalRepository is an interface,your code will work. otherwise you should use :

```
 @Module
 @InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
 object XYZModule {

 // with Potential dependencies if exists
 @Provides
 fun providePrincipalRepo(dep1:DEP1,dep2:DEP2): PrincipalRepository {
  return  PrincipalRepositoryImpl(dep1,dep2);
 }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: I am getting same issue as OP and this didn't fix it.